# How to remove X button on video overlay?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, youtube

YouTube version 15.08.52 on Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop) is showing a X button on the video overlay user interface and it has to be tapped to hide the UI.

[image]

I searched on the internet and some posts say it's because the accessibility options "Switch Access" and "Accessibility Menu" are turned on, but in my case, the setting Switch Access is off and there is no option for Accessibility Menu.

How can I disable the option to show the X button so that the UI is hidden automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open YouTube
2. Click on your picture on the top-right corner
3. Click on settings
4. Click on Accessibility
5. Disable the thing.

Comment: Oh wow! Is this option only available on the latest release? When I searched on google I couldn't find anything related to that.